# How can I get a js variable into iframe

Tags: javascript, variables, iframe, get

I have a dynamically created iframe

this iframe has js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.devicePixelRatio >= 2) {
document.body.className += ' is_2x';
}
domReady();
Subscribe.init({id: 0, hash: '6ec859bd0192095f3b', oid: 15898180});;vk.id = 0;
</script>
```

i need get the Subscribe.init() value from parent window

thanks

ps. I don't have edit permissions to this iframe.  I need this value like text

Comment: I think this is not possible for security-reasons in most browsers. If it was possible, an iFrame you put into your webpage (for example a youtube video) could interfer with your main-pages scripts and contents, doing all kind of evil stuff.

Comment: assuming no CORs is available and your apps on on different domains, JSON.stringify the data and append it to the url hash of the iframe from the parent. in the frame, you can JSON.parse(location.hash.slice(1)) to get the object back. you can also use the "window.name" hack, or postMessage().

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't run into `Cross Domain Scripting` issues (`IFRAME` is within the same domain as the parent window, or `CORS` is enabled and configured), you can try:

```
window.parent.Subscribe.init({id: 0, hash: '6ec859bd0192095f3b', oid: 15898180});
```

More about security issues you may encounter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy